# Delete rows and keep only last value in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

To keep things simple, here's a sample structure:

```
    id   |      otherId   |        date       | actionId  |
__________________________________________________________
    1             30          09.06.2017 10:22     5   
    2             30          09.06.2017 10:24     5
    3             31          09.06.2017 10:24     4
    4             32          09.06.2017 10:25     2
    5             32          09.06.2017 10:26     2
```

The id is autoincremented field.
As you may see, otherId=30 value has 2 rows and I need to only have the most recent one. So keep the row with id=2 and delete all others.Same goes for otherId=32.

Is there a simple way to run a sql command to achieve this or only by going and checking row by row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to delete all rows for wich a row with the same `otherId` but a larger `id` value exists. In SQL:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM MyTable AS T2
              WHERE T2.otherId = MyTable.otherId
                AND T2.id      > MyTable.id);
```